# Erlang 'typer' command is not found (Homebrew installation on macOS)

Tags: macos, erlang, homebrew

I installed Erlang (version 20.3.1) using `brew install erlang` on macOS 10.13.3.

`erl` and `dialyzer` seem to be working fine, but `typer` is unavailable:

```
mac:user$ typer my_module.erl
-bash: typer: command not found

mac:user$ which erl
/usr/local/bin/erl
```

Does `typer` need to be installed separately?

I thought it was a part of the standard distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not symlinked via Homebrew, but it is installed.

It's at `/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/$ERL_VERSION/lib/erlang/bin/typer`.

Comment: Will do! I'll accept as soon as Stack Overflow lets me (~4 mins).